# Application scalability - design

Tags: architecture

I have developed a web application in php which could be used for automating manual processes in a clinic. The application works well and 3 concurrent users can use the application without any performance issues.

Standard transactions are querying, creating new records, modifying existing records and scheduling appointments. As of now the application is deployed on a standard web hosting server.

If this application was to be used by 20 concurrent users I am sure the performance would be miserable.

In a scenario, if the clinic decides to implement their own web server and host this application, 
1) what does it take in terms of 'system' architecture/design as a whole to scale up my application for multiple (20-30) concurrent users?
2) Do I need to change my code in order to scale up? 
3) How do I decide on the resource capacity of my web server in terms of processing and memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am sure the performance would be miserable

How do you know this?  Have you tested?  Never [pre-optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  Run a test, see what falls down.  You might be surprised.

After you build your test suite ([lots of open source tools available](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)), take a look at what broke.  Did you database fail?  Did you actually become CPU bound?  Did you run out of memory?  Look at getting a more powerful machine.  Or hosting it in the cloud where you can scale up to more powerful servers at need.

20-30 concurrent users is not much load.  Remember, users are mostly idle.  If a request to your site takes 1 second, and the user spends 10 seconds (that's really fast) looking at the response.  Then your server is really only handling 2-3 concurrent *requests*.  Considering most modern processors have 4 cores, you probably are not even saturating a single CPU.

Also, take your hourly rate, multiply it by the number of hours it will take you to build the new system.  Now compare that to your hosting costs.  It's very likely that you shouldn't spend any time on this at all.  Find a better hosting plan with dedicated servers before you rebuild.

Now that we've covered that, if you really want to learn how to develop a system that will scale, learn about basic architectural patterns like MVC, or Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), etc.  Most of these will tend to help you build systems that won't let you get into too much trouble.

Considering that this seems a very database-centric application, you are much more likely saturating your disk IO of your database (that's kind of a neat trick with 2-3 concurrent requests).  If you do have a disk too busy, you can look at caching solutions.  They are usually the first solution space when you are optimizing for performance, especially database performance.  Look at what data can be cached, more static information like company addresses and names and such.  If you can cache that in the client, so much the better.

So... tldr;  You probably will be fine, if not, figure out why you aren't fine before you build a new system.  And even if you aren't fine.  See if you can't buy your way into being fine.

Comment: Thanks Rob! That was a very detailed answer and gave me a clear idea.